# Type error minimizing API requests with Angular 4 Observables

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a service that makes an API request that works fine:

```
@Injectable()
export class TourService {
  private touringUrl: string = `http://localhost/error-records/api/tour`;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getTouringBands(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.touringUrl)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .map(touringArists => touringArists
      .map(artist => new TouringArtist(
        artist.field_touring_artist_name[0].value,
        artist.field_touring_artist_id[0].value
      ))
    )
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

but the problem is, every time a user navigates to the page and back, a new request is made. I'm coming from React-Redux, where I would generally hold it in state, check the state, and then only make the API call if necessary. However, when I try something like that, I get a type error.

```
@Injectable()
export class TourService {
  private touringUrl: string = `http://localhost/error-records/api/tour`;
  private touringArists: TouringArtist[];

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getTouringBands(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.touringArtists) {
      return this.touringArtists;
    }
    return this.http.get(this.touringUrl)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .map(touringArists => {
      const artists = touringArists.map(artist => new TouringArtist(
        artist.field_touring_artist_name[0].value,
        artist.field_touring_artist_id[0].value
      ))
      this.touringArtists = artists;
      return artists;
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

If I try the above code, I get the error `Type 'TouringArtist[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'. Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'TouringArtist[]'.`

Comment: On the second line of your function you are returning an array but Typescript expects an Observable<any> because you told it that that is the return type for the function. You can return an observable by changing line #2 to: `return Observable.of(this.touringArtists);`

Comment: Thanks @bygrace! That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 getTouringBands(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.touringArtists) {
      return this.touringArtists;
    }
```

In the first line, you say that the return of the function is `Observable<any>`.
Inside the `if` condition you return `touringArtists`, which is `ouringArtist[]`.

You can return it as an observable like:

```
 getTouringBands(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.touringArtists) {
      return Observable.of(this.touringArtists);
    }
```